# Ozonolysis mechanism question

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, ozone

[image]

Is this mechanism will be similar to ozonolysis ?

My try : 
[image]

My Question is will B be the answer ? And what does Me2S do ?

Comment: Definitely Yes.

Comment: Me2S reduces the ozonide and any remaining ozone. I think the reaction will take place on the more electron rich double bond. The product you have drawn is not one of the options offered among the answers.

Comment: @Waylander should the Answer be B ?

Comment: I highly doubt that the reagent in the first step is O2, and if that's the case, then it's oxidation reaction. But, I'm not sure!

Comment: @rv7 its O3 ,Ozonolysis will happen I think

Comment: B is the only product that has the terminal carbons at the correct oxidation state. If you want a diol work up with borohydride

Comment: As Waylander pointed out, you lost a carbon in your product.

Comment: The question could have been improved by modifying the reagents as follows: 1) 1 equiv. O3; 2) excess Me2S, -78 deg. C.

Comment: @Zhe, Ignoring the options, why didn't the ozonide form on the other alkene(the one with the methyl group?). Sorry for disturbing you, but I have encountered this question myself, and am confused regarding this.

Comment: @B.Anshuman I assume ozone, with 3 oxygens, is more reactive with electron-rich alkenes than the reverse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first part of your question has been answered in the comment, as for the part about what does $\ce{Me2S}$ do:
The mechanism used here is reductive ozonolysis and $\ce{Me2S}$ acts a reducing reducing agent itself getting oxidised to dimethysulphoxide $\ce{(Me)2SO}$ (DMSO).
As for the mechanism of reductive ozonolysis with $\ce{Me2S}$ here's a helpful [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PcO49xCb4Gs&t=282s).